# What is the difference between "$\forall a :\forall b:P(a) \implies Q(b)$" and "$(\forall a:P(a))\implies(\forall b:Q(b))$"?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The type of a is proper subset of the type of b.
“$\forall a:\forall b:P(a)\implies Q(b)$" and "$(\forall a:P(a))\implies(\forall b:Q(b))$”
Are they equal?

Comment: It's not clear to me how to parse the first one.  Is it
$\forall a\; \forall b\; \left(P(a) \implies Q(b)\right)$, or is it
$\left(\forall a\; \forall b\; P(a)\right) \implies Q(b)$?

Answer (score 0):

No; they are not.

$\forall a:\forall b: (P(a)\to Q(b))$ means "for every two things, if one is $P$ then the other is $Q$".  Thus if there's is *anything* that is $P$, then everything is $Q$.

This is equivalent to $(\exists a: P(a)) \to (\forall b: Q(b))\;$.

...

On the other flipper, $( \forall a: P(a) )\to (\forall b: Q(b))$ means "if *every* $a$ is $P$ then every $b$ is $Q$."   That is not the same thing.

---

$$\begin{align} &\forall a  : \forall b : [P(a) \to Q(b)]
\\[1ex] \iff & (\text{implication equivalence})
\\[1ex]&\forall a :\forall b: (\neg P(a) \vee Q(b))
\\[1ex] \iff & (b\text{ is free in } P)
\\[1ex]&\forall a : (\neg P(a) \vee (\forall b : Q(b)))
\\[1ex] \iff & (a\text{ is free in }Q)
\\[1ex]&(\forall a : \neg P(a)) \vee (\forall b : Q(b))
\\[1ex] \iff & (\text{dual negation})
\\[1ex]&(\neg \exists a : P(a)) \vee (\forall : b Q(b))
\\[1ex] \iff & (\text{implication equivalence})
\\[1ex]&(\exists a : P(a)) \to (\forall b : Q(b))
\end{align}$$