# Universal quantifier distributes over implication

Tags: logic, quantifiers

Is

> $\forall x \forall y: P(x) \to Q(y)$

the same thing as

> $(\forall x P(x)) \to (\forall y:Q(y))$

?

If not can someone give an example as to why it isn't?

I'm not getting the whole meaning of $\forall x \forall y:P(x) \to Q(y)$ at all. Does that mean for if $P(x)$ is satisfied, then $Q(y)$ is satisfied for all $y$? Or does it mean that if $P(x)$ is satisfied, then there is some $y$ out there that satisfied $Q(y)$?

Comment: there is no typo. Idk if this helps but P(x) is a predicate on set P which is a subset of the set Q and Q(y) is a predicate for set Q

Answer (score 1):

Let $P(x)$ be a statement which is sometimes true **and** sometimes false; likewise for $Q(y)$.  Then

- $P(x)\to Q(y)$ is sometimes false, so $\forall x\forall y (P(x)\to Q(y))$ is false;
- but $(\forall x P(x))$ is false, so $(\forall x P(x))\to(\forall y Q(y))$ is true.

So the two formulae do not mean the same thing.

Comment: so are x and y the same elements of the set? I'm not understanding what $\forall x\forall y (P(x)\to Q(y))$ is saying. If P(x) and Q(y) are both statements on two sets where one is a subset of the other one, then can you make up an example for P and Q? The two universal quantifies are confusing me . Is it saying that for every element in set P that satistys P(x) implies that some element in set Q satisfys Q(y)?

Comment: $P(x)$ is any statement about a variable $x$ and $Q(y)$ is any statement about a variable $y$.  Depending on what $P,Q,x$ and $y$ are the statement $P(x)\to Q(y)$, which means "if $P(x)$ is true then $Q(y)$ is true", is either true or false.  Take some specific meaning for $P$ and $Q$.  The statement $\forall x\forall y (P(x)\to Q(y))$ says that $P(x)\to Q(y)$ is true for all possible choices of $x,y$.

Comment: @Kyle - It may help to "incarnate" David's example into a simple mathematical one. Consider as $P(x)$ : $x=0$ and as $Q(y)$ : $y > 0$ and consider the *domain* $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers. We have that both $\forall x(x=0)$ and $\forall y(y > 0)$ are *false* in $\mathbb N$; thus, by truth conditions for $\rightarrow$ : $\forall x(x=0) \rightarrow \forall y(y > 0)$ is *true*. Consider now $(x = 0) \rightarrow (y > 0)$; for $0$ as value for both $x$ and $y$ we have : $(0 = 0) \rightarrow (0 > 0)$, which is *false* ($TRUE \rightarrow FALSE$ is $FALSE$). 1/2

Comment: Thus $\forall y[(0=0)→(y>0)]$ is *false* and also $\forall x \forall y[(x=0)→(y>0)]$ is. Conclusion : the two formulae are **not** equivalent and thus - as per David's answer - they have not "the same meaning". 2/2

Answer (score 1):

As per [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1141480/what-is-the-difference-between-forall-a-forall-bpa-implies-qb-and)

No; they are not.

$\forall x\;\forall y\; (P(x)\to Q(y))$ means "for every two things, if one is $P$ then the other is $Q$".  Thus if there's is *anything* that is $P$, then everything is $Q$.

This is equivalent to $(\exists x\; P(x)) \to (\forall y\; Q(y))\;$.

...

On the other flipper, $( \forall x\; P(x) )\to (\forall y\; Q(y))$ means "if *every* $x$ is $P$ then every $y$ is $Q$."   That is not the same thing.

---

$$\begin{align} &\forall x\; \forall y\; [P(x) \to Q(y)]
\\[1ex] \iff & (\text{implication equivalence})
\\[1ex]&\forall x\;\forall y\; (\neg P(x) \vee Q(y))
\\[1ex] \iff & (y\text{ is free in } P(x))
\\[1ex]&\forall x\; (\neg P(x) \vee (\forall y\; Q(y)))
\\[1ex] \iff & (x\text{ is free in }\forall y\;Q(y))
\\[1ex]&(\forall x\; \neg P(x)) \vee (\forall y\; Q(y))
\\[1ex] \iff & (\text{dual negation})
\\[1ex]&(\neg \exists x\; P(x)) \vee (\forall y\; Q(y))
\\[1ex] \iff & (\text{implication equivalence})
\\[1ex]&(\exists x\; P(x)) \to (\forall y\; Q(y))
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\forall x \forall y : (Px \to Qy)
$$
means: If you pick any $x$ you want, and you at the same time independently pick any $y$ you want, it must be true that $P(x) \to Q(y)$.  So either $P(x)$ is false for that pair $x,y$, or $P(x)$ is true and $Q(y)$ is true.

This is not equivalent to $(\forall x : Px) \to (\forall y : Qy)$.  The latter, as it turns out, is instead equivalent to
$$
\exists x \forall y : (Px \to Qy).
$$